# Can't move file from /sdcard/ to /system/app/ with shell, even with su.

Tags: android

***Note:*** I am running this on a rooted device.

From my application, if I try to move a file from `/sdcard/` to `/system/app/` it fails. The following shell script does not work:

```
su
mount -o remount,rw /system
mv /sdcard/file.apk /system/app/file.apk
```

Whereas the following will work:

```
su
mount -o remount,rw /system
mv /system/app/file.apk /system/app/file.apk.bak
```

Why doesn't it work when copying from /sdcard/? (or any other file location I've tried).

I can't see the output from the location I'm running this however if I try from ADB then it gives me an error that the source file was not found even though it definitely exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
adb root    
adb remount
adb push my-app.apk /sdcard/
adb shell
su
cd /sdcard
mv my-app.apk /system/priv-app
cd  /system/priv-app
chmod 777 my-app.apk
```

This worked for me on a rooted device

Comment: I'm doing this programmatically from my app on the device -doesn't ADB have to be from a PC?

Answer (score 0):

```
adb root
adb remount
adb push [local-file.apk] /system/app/file.apk
adb reboot
```

Comment: I'm doing this programmatically from my app on the device -doesn't ADB have to be from a PC?